# ProgressBar during ToList when retrieving MongoDB documents

Tags: winforms, async-await, mongodb-query, progress-bar

I have many thousands of documents that will be retrieved, jiggered at bit and displayed in a data grid.  The whole situation can take 10-30 seconds and want a visual showing progress (something more substantive than a marquee progress bar)

The goal is to update a status field with the number of documents currently retrieved as they get brought in through `ToList()` (or should it be `ToListAsync()`).  Suppose the progress update rate is to have callback every 250ms show the current document count (or list length ?).  I'm not sure how to instruct the task to perform a callback that would assist the progress / status updater, or how to setup `ToList` to do progress calls.

```
private async void CollectionDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string collectionName = collectionDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // progressBar/status begin stuff
        await LoadCollection(collectionName);
        // progressBar/status finish stuff

        … set the datagrid datasource to the datatable
}

private Task LoadCollection(string collectionName) 
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Ne("Type", "Header") & builder.Ne("Type", (string)null);

        var collectionDocuments =
            Database
            .GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName)
            .Find(filter)
            .ToList()                    
        ;
        … 
        // reshape documents into a DataTable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1):

```
private async void CollectionDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // ...

        var progress = new Progress<int>(n => /* show progress */);

        await LoadCollection(collectionName, progress);

        // ...
}

private Task LoadCollection(string collectionName, IProgress<int> progress) 
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // ...

        progress.Report(i);

        // ...
    }
}
```

I don't know if MongoDB has asynchronous APIs. If it does, you might even get rid of `Task.Run`.

Comment: There is a `ToListAsync()`.  Can you think of a way to invoke the `Report` from the *interior* of the `ToList` ?

Comment: Only if `ToListAsync` as an `IProgress` argmument. This is an HTTP request that is 1 request with 1 response. you only know it's multiple items when the response is parsed. You can always have a marquee for the HTTP part and a count for your processing (which might make the whole thing slower).